# Calling static classes from controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, class, controller

I can call the static classes from a view (cshtml), but not from the controller, for example :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace TEST
{
    public static class Tool
    {
        public static Dictionary<string, string> CreateHeadTailTable()
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> source =
               new Dictionary<string, string>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                source.Add(i.ToString(), "");
            }
            return source;
        }
    }
}
```

Now in the controller, I want to use the function, but I can't :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using TEST; 

namespace TEST.Controllers
{
    public class CityController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /City/

        public string Index(string cityID)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cityID) || cityID.Length < 3)
                return "error"; //RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

            // **can call TEST.Tool.CreateHeadTailTable or Tool.CreateHeadTailTable here** 

            return "get " +  cityID.Substring(cityID.Length - 3, 3);
        }

    }
}
```

But I can call the classes from views(cshtml) without any problems

Comment: Should that be `Tool.CreateHeadTailTable` (not `TEST`)

Comment: Now its `Tools` (plural) but the class is `Tool`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Sorry again!

Comment: Works fine for me. `Dictionary<string, string> result = Tool.CreateHeadTailTable();` returns 10 items

Comment: It's so strange, I can't figure out why!

Comment: What do you mean by you Can't? What error you get? Compile time or runtime?

Comment: @SBirthare I don't have any errors, I just can't "see" the class, can't call it!

Comment: I hope you have built the project at least once. What if you write the code anyway and build?

Comment: @SBirthare it will give me the error : The name 'Tool' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Weird, close the visual studio and build again.

Comment: I restarted the studio but the problem still persists

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64210/discussion-between-sbirthare-and-hoangnnm).